# Handling javascript db.transaction callback

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-callback

I'm stuck with the following and I'm sure it's do to my lack of experience dealing with callbacks, I want to query a db as follows:

```
db.transaction(queryFoodDBAll, errorCB);

function errorCB(tx, err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
}

function queryFoodDBAll(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Food', [], displayAllFood, errorCB);
}

function displayAllFood(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    var items = new Array();
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        items[i] = results.rows.item(i).data
    }
    printdata('settings-food',items, 'Food');
}

function printData(type,data,title) {
    switch(type)
    {
        case 'settings-food':
            alert("Data: "+data);
            var content = '<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="c"><h3>'+title+'</h3>';
            for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                content += '<p>'+data[i]+'</p>';
            }
            content += '</div>';
            $("#settings-food").append(content);
            break;
}
```

Now, when I run it, all the information is retrieved successfully until I run the printData function, which gives me the the errorCB displaying "Error processing SQL: undefined".

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is the return stack:

When you get to printData your call stack looks like this:

```
----queryFoodDAll
----executeSQL
----disiplayAllFood (jump to printData)
----errorCB
----printData
```

Javascript will return up that call stack; so while you skipped `errorCB` on your way down, on the way back up it hits that function, no matter what you do; because it's part of the callback stack.

What you want to do is not have your `errorCB` as a call back function.

Instead check in your `displayAllFood()` for valid SQL. If its valid continue down the call list (meaning continue onto `printData`) but if its *not* valid then call `errorCB`.